# Hibernate/JTA Transaction cannot proceed: STATUS_COMMITTED when trying to close connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wildfly

I enabled Hibernate logs to DEBUG and noticed that it was having troubles with respect to releasing the connections -

> 2018-10-09 16:33:26,217 TRACE [default
>   task-14]-[org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl]
>   Releasing JDBC resources 2018-10-09 16:33:26,217 TRACE [default
>   task-14]-[org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl]
>   Closing logical connection 2018-10-09 16:33:26,217 DEBUG [default
>   task-14]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] could not
>   clear warnings: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031070: Transaction cannot
>   proceed: STATUS_COMMITTED

Although it doesn't seem to cause any application errors, I am extremely worried that Hibernate might not be releasing its connections gracefully and therefore could result in connection leaks.

I am running Hibernate with JTA on Wildfly 11 for the record, and the Session Factory configuration(via Spring) is as follows -

```
hibernate.jta.UserTransaction=UserTransaction
hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager=java:jboss/infinispan/hibernate        
hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class=org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl
hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory
hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
```

It seems to me as though Hibernate is not aware of the JTA Transactions being closed - is there something that I might have missed configuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like Hibernate and Spring weren't in sync with the Transaction Synchronizations. Setting the jtaTransactionManager on the LocalSessionFactoryBean stopped this error.

Old Spring docs refer this issue - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch14s02.html (Sec 14.2.10 Spurious application server warnings when using Hibernate)